# .OBN Format: Edit and Reconvert Back

Tags: binaryfiles, file-conversion

I have OBN formatted binary files. To convert it to a text based file, I use a command in unix like-

```
dd if=FileName.OBN of=Output.txt ibs=1169 obs=1169 cbs=1169 conv=ascii
```

Where -

```
if : is input file     
of : is output file    
ibs: input block size obs: output    
block size cbs: new line insert at    
block size conv: convert to
```

After I edit, how do I convert it back to the original format without breaking the format?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured it out. The default ibs is 512. So after you edit the text file, you can convert it back to OBN by issuing the command-

```
dd if=Output.txt of=FileName.OBN ibs=1169 obs=1169 cbs=1169 conv=ebcdic
```